# How to assign parameters and different controller method to button_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am surprisingly having a hard time making `button_to` work the way I want to in Rails. I am inside users show page (`localhost:3000/users/1`). I want to `create` an availability (`availability_controller.rb`) from there. I have a `create` method inside availability controller.

Here is the availability controller:

```
  def create
    @availability = current_user.availability.build(available_on: Date.today, available_hour: params[:available_hour])
    if @availability.save
      flash[:notice] = "New availability added!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error adding availability"
      redirect_to current_user
    end
  end
```

It takes in a params, `available_hour`.

I was, fortunately, able to create a form to do what I need using `form` method:

```
<form method="post" action="/availability">
  <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
  <button name="available_hour" value=0 type="submit" class="nowhere-block">Add Availability</button>
</form>
```

I hardcoded value of 0 to be sent to availability create method whenever user clicked on the button. This works great and I can probably go on with life.

However, I thought the code above is a little verbose, I wanted to achieve the same thing with `button_to`. I have looked at the [button_to docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) but I could not find the information I am looking for.

I tried `<%= button_to "Post Availability", @availability, { available_hour: 5 } %>` but it gave me `No route matches [POST] "/users/1"` error. Somehow it is still accessing user path.

I have tried other combinations as well unsuccessfully:

```
<%= button_to "Post Availability", availability_path, {controller: "availability", available_hour: 5 } %>
<%= button_to "Post Availability", @availability, remote: true, class: "nowhere-block" %>
```

How can I, from inside user show, access availability controller's create method?

Update:
Current routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  resources :friendships
  resources :availability
  root to: "users#index"


 availability_index GET    /availability(.:format)          availability#index
                         POST   /availability(.:format)          availability#create
        new_availability GET    /availability/new(.:format)      availability#new
       edit_availability GET    /availability/:id/edit(.:format) availability#edit
            availability GET    /availability/:id(.:format)      availability#show
                         PATCH  /availability/:id(.:format)      availability#update
                         PUT    /availability/:id(.:format)      availability#update
                         DELETE /availability/:id(.:format)      availability#destroy
```

Comment: Have you tried to put the parameters in the path that you want : ```button_to "Post Availability", availability_path(available_hour: 5)``` ?

Comment: are you adding a resource route in config/route.rb? availability_path is a helper method derived from the route.rb file.

Comment: @ScottMonceaux, I updated my post to show routes. As far as I know, I have `resources :availability` included. 

Raphael, I got `No route matches [POST] "/availability/1"` error when I tried that.

Comment: Can you run rake routes and post the findings? I suspect it has something to do with the fact it isn't plural. For smiles and grins also try changing resources to resource for availability and let us know what you get.

Comment: @ScottMonceaux I updated my post. Sorry, I am not sure the second one - do you mind elaborating changing `resources to resources for availability`?

Comment: Instead of resources :availability use resource :availability and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a parameter wrong, also if you want to use `@availability` have to be defined in users_controller#show as `@availability = Availability.new`

**Answer**

```
<%= button_to "Post Availability", availability_path(available_hour: 5) %>
#or
<%= button_to "Post Availability", Availability.new, params: {available_hour: 5} %>
```

Comment: Thanks fort the reply, @7urkm3n! I am not planning to use the users_controller in the first place. I wanted to invoke the `create` method inside other controller, namely `availability_controller`. Do you think it is a bad practice?

Comment: @Iggy its alright but depends how u want to use routes, like only available under users then make it nested routes, instead of keeping alone. Is my post both supposed to work even keeping them in separate controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<%= button_to "Post Availability", availability_path(available_hour: 5) %>`